# What functions are called when tableview cell is pressed?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiimageview, cell, uicollectionviewcell

When `cellForRowAt` is called I set each of the cells imageView's to nil (this is to clean up in case a reused cell is keeping its recycled contents), then I lazily fetch a gif from giphy's api.  When the gif from giphy's api returns, I set the image of the cell to nil (otherwise the gifs will simply overlap), then to that newly arrived gif.  This behaves as expected; if the gif takes a long time to arrive, I have the placeholder gif to signal to the user that work is being done.  When the fetched gif finally does arrive, it replaces the placeholder.

Here is the problem.  When I press down on a cell, the placeholder comes back and overlaps the proper gif.  I'm having trouble figuring out how to debug this because I have no idea what functions are called when I press down on a cell.  `didSelectRowAt` and `cellForRowAt` are not called when I press down on a cell.  `didSelectRowAt` is only called after you release your touch.

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let row = indexPath.row
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: giphCellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! GifTableViewCell
    print(#line, "<-Reached")
    cell.imageView?.image = nil
    cell.imageView?.loadGif(name: "giphyLogo")

    setCellAppearance(cell, row)

    cell.btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnPress), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.btn.tag = row

    cell.favoriteBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(alterFavCount), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.favoriteBtn.tag = row

    return cell
    }


func setCellAppearance(_ cell: GifTableViewCell, _ row: Int) {
    isScrollingUp = row > lastCellForRowAtIndex
    lastCellForRowAtIndex = row


    if showOnlyFavorites {
        if let data = onlyFavoriteGifs[row].value(forKey: "data") as? Data {

            cell.img.downloadImageFrom(data)
        } else {
            cell.img.downloadImageFrom(cell, link: (onlyFavoriteGifs[row].value(forKey: "url") as? String)!, row, showOnlyFavorites)
        }
        cell.favoriteBtn.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "purpleHeartR"), for: .normal)
    } else {
        if let data = GifCache.shared.general.object(forKey: row as AnyObject) {
            print(#line, "<-Reached")
            cell.img.image = nil
            cell.img.downloadImageFrom(data as! Data)
        } else {
            print(#line, "<-Reached")
            cell.img.downloadImageFrom(cell, link: giphs[row].url, row, showOnlyFavorites)
        }

        if let wasSelected = buttonStates[giphs[row].url] {
            if wasSelected {
                cell.favoriteBtn.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "purpleHeartR"), for: .normal)
            } else {
                cell.favoriteBtn.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "WhiteHeartR"), for: .normal)
            }
        } else {
            cell.favoriteBtn.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "WhiteHeartR"), for: .normal)
        }
    }
}


extension UIImageView {
    func downloadImageFrom(_ cell: UITableViewCell, link:String, _ row: Int, _ favsOnly: Bool)  {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask( with: NSURL(string:link)! as URL, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print("error", error!, Date())
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print(#line, "<-Reached")
            self.image = nil
            self.contentMode =  UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
            if let data = data {
                let img = UIImage.gif(data: data)
                self.image = img

                DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                    GifCache.shared.general.setObject(data as AnyObject, forKey: row as AnyObject)
                }
            }

        }
    }).resume()

}

func downloadImageFrom(_ data: Data) {
    print(#line, "<-Reached")
    self.image = nil
    let img = UIImage.gif(data: data)
    self.image = img

    }
}
```

Comment: Scan the documentation for `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` and you will find your answer.

Comment: Take a look at your `setHighlighted` function in `GifTableViewCell`. If your subclass doesn't have that, consider adding it to customize the highlight behavior.

Comment: I've looked through UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate documentation I haven't found anything useful.  Note: didselectrow does not satisfy my query, because that is called after you release your press.

Comment: @rmaddy, I couldn't find it in the documentation.  Do you know of a delegate function that is called when you press down on a cell (not release, in otherwords didselectrowat doesn't help).